# Error streaming high quality FLV over RTMP with Red5

Tags: flash, video, flv, red5, rtmp

I'm rather new to the FLV streaming/Red5 scene and have found that for some reason I cannot playback FLV files encoded above a certain quality using the oflaDemo. I've encoded the FLV files from h264 to Sorenson Spark using ffmpeg. It works using `-qscale 31`, but anything much higher (the number seems to change between different movies) refuses to play. Is there an upper limit on the bitrate for Sorenson Spark FLVs or is it a Red5 problem (or indeed a Flash problem)?

My ultimate goal is to stream high quality video to the Wii, hence using "old" Flash 7 formats! Maybe there is another way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks this will help but you may try to set the packet size when you encode (-ps) in case your server is being restrictive on that level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of this particular issue (being a red5 developer) but I do know that the server has no concern about the quality of a video and it will try to send it as quickly and efficiently as possible. In most cases it seems that the Flash Player fails or locks up before the server will, especially with large F4V or MP3 files.